# Can I test just the code in a single module?

Tags: rust

I've got a Rust project that uses a fairly large framework. Compilation and macro expansion take a really long time. If I make a tiny change to the code, it takes a minute or more before before "cargo test" actually executes.

Is it possible to create a sub-project or sub-module within the same crate and test just the code in the module, assuming there are no dependencies on code outside the module?

Comment: The compilation unit in Rust is a crate, not a module. So you'd have to split this code out into another crate to avoid compiling the rest of it.

Comment: You are asking "can I test just a single module" (the answer is yes), but your actual question seems to be "can I *compile* just a single module" (which seems to be no)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested in "cargo workspaces" (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html).

Essentially, instead of splitting your code into multiple `mod`s, you split it into multiple crates. These crates can depend on each other via "path dependencies". For example, you could have something like:

```rust
[dependencies]
my_helper_crate = { path = "path/to/crate" }
```

The book has much more detail on this, but a nice feature of using workspaces is that your crates can have separate `Cargo.toml`s, but share a `Cargo.lock`, so you won't get issues around incompatible versions of crates.

With this setup, you can build one crate without building the rest of them, so you can cut down on a dev feedback loop.

However, if you have `crate_a` which depends on `crate_b`, building `crate_a` still requires building `crate_b`, there's not really any getting around that. The benefit is mainly for the leaves of your dependency graph.

Comment: I think this may be the way I have to do it. A complicating factor is that a lot of the code is interdependent, and Rust does not allow cyclic dependencies between crates. This will likely force the creation of more subcrates than I would like.

Comment: Yeah it's not always ideal, I'd recommend reading this article: https://matklad.github.io/2021/09/04/fast-rust-builds.html . It has some great ideas more generally about improving build times. A key takeaway is that multi-crate workspaces have an additional advantage of improving parallelism, which is likely to be a general speedup on your (probably multicore) CPU

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `cargo test` will take arguments which match specific tests that you want to run ([Cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html)). For example, if you have modules `foo` and `bar`, you can run `cargo test foo` to run tests from that module, excluding all others.

Comment: Thanks, but this forces a full compile, which takes a minute. What I'm looking to do is create and execute a target consisting of that one module only.

Comment: @ccleve I don't know of a way to only compile a single module, though somebody else may have a trick for that. The best solution that I have in that case would be to break it down into smaller libraries which contain related modules. Libraries can be compiled individually, but that would probably be a large refactor if you already have issues with compile times.